# Tomcat Maven- Failed to start component issue

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to setup a spring boot maven project to use spring batch for job multithreading. I am running into an issue in setup.

I'm getting the following error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
```

My POM file is as follows:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.db.afc_ncm</groupId>
<artifactId>DataIngestion</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>DataIngestion</name>
<description>Spring Batch Parallel Step</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>com.db.afc_ncm.Application</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-service</artifactId>
        <version>0.13.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.db.afc_ncm</groupId>
        <artifactId>ImpalaJDBC41</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/lib_ImpalaJDBC41.jar</systemPath>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Full Stack Trace:

```
2019-03-18 14:44:18.524  INFO 36404 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-03-18 14:44:18.528  INFO 36404 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.32
2019-03-18 14:44:18.549  INFO 36404 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Application Virtualization Client;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICAService\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\System32\;C:\PROGRAM FILES\CITRIX\System32\;C:\PROGRAM FILES\CITRIX\ICAService\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Citrix\System32;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\PROGRAM FILES\CITRIX\Virtual Desktop Agent\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVClient\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\; C:\Users\prassuha\.m2\repository\org\testng\testng\5.12.1\testng-5.12.1.jar; C:\Users\prassuha\Anaconda3\Scripts;.]
2019-03-18 14:44:18.835 ERROR 36404 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:182) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    ... 10 common frames omitted

2019-03-18 14:44:18.836 ERROR 36404 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) [spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.javasampleapproach.batch.parallelstep.SpringBatchParallelStepApplication.main(SpringBatchParallelStepApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    ... 6 common frames omitted

2019-03-18 14:44:18.838  INFO 36404 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any ideas on what I could exclude or include to make this go away?

Comment: Why do you have both `spring-boot-starter` and `spring-boot-starter-web` dependencies? Is there a specific reason for this? As far as I can see, you don't need the `spring-boot-starter`. Remove this and keep the `spring-boot-starter-web`. That is of cause if you need this to run on a tomcat server. If you don't want the project to run on a tomcat server, and just wanna do some batch processing, use `spring-boot-batch-starter`

Comment: Made the changes, still have the same issue. I edited the prompt with the updated pom file. Any other thoughts? I do need starter-web because I'm using a web endpoint to trigger a mysql instance.

Comment: The problem is your servlet-api version. It should be upgraded. Try upgrading it to the latest. If you don't want the latest version to be used, try upgrading version 3.1 or up.

Comment: Also, clean and rebuild the project after the changes.

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace

Comment: @k9yosh yes i do clean and rebuild after changing each time. Aris_Kortex, added stack trace

Comment: Did you change the `servlet-api` version? Because that's an issue. Your spring boot version uses Tomcat 8.5 which requires `servlet-api` version 3.1

Comment: Everytime I try to change it the build fails. I think my parent release version (company project release) is limiting the version to 2.5

Comment: So yeah, your issue is the 'servlet-api' version. What you can do is remove the `spring-boot-starter-web` tomcat instance and use your own. And `servlet-api` version 2.5 runs only in Tomcat 6.0.x

Comment: To be honest I'm trying to build a simple batch processor, I don't need a web component. How can I get rid of the tomcat instance from my spring boot dependency?

Comment: remove the `spring-boot-starter-web` and add `spring-boot-batch-starter`

Comment: Sorry it should be `spring-boot-starter-batch` not `spring-boot-batch-starter`

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your spring boot version uses Apache Tomcat 8.5 when you include the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency, which requires a `servlet-api` version of 3.1. This is what causes this exception. If you need the project to be a web project, you can up the `servlet-api` dependency version to 3.1. Else if you just want to do some batch processing without having web functionalities, just remove the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency and add `spring-boot-starter-batch`

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up. I did that but it's still trying to start tomcat (same error trace). Please check edited prompt for how my updated pom looks like.

Comment: @ravecoder How did you generate this project? As in, did you use any tool? or you just used a pom from somewhere else? You can't use the same run configuration since this is not a Web application anymore. You need to make sure that this runs as a normal application. If you don't mind porting this code to a new, clean project [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) is a great place to start.

Comment: Yes, I used Spring Initializr before. I'll try to rebuild with a new template from there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the version of (tomcat-embed-jasper ) , it will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).